# BizTalk: An internal server error was encountered while attempting to transmit the message

Tags: c#, wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2016

I am having trouble pushing a message through WCF-Custom adapter (wsHTTP binding). I am using custom endpoint behaviour extension MessageInspector to remove MessageID, ReplyTo, To & Action nodes from the SOAP Envelope. There are no errors shown while debugging the endpoint behaviour class but I keep getting 'An internal server error was encountered while attempting to transmit the message' error with BizTalk NACK. The code in BeforeSendRequest method of the endpoint behaviour class is :

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
    try
    {
        MessageBuffer messageBuffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
        Message message = messageBuffer.CreateMessage();
        messageBuffer.Close();

        MemoryStream msOriginal = new MemoryStream();
        XmlWriter xwOriginal = XmlWriter.Create(msOriginal);
        message.WriteMessage(xwOriginal);
        xwOriginal.Flush();
        string originalMsg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msOriginal.ToArray());
        xwOriginal.Close();

        msOriginal.Position = 0;

        msOriginal = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalMsg));
        XmlDictionaryReader xdrOriginal = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(msOriginal, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xdrOriginal);

        var rootMsgElement = xdoc.Root;
        //string rootNameSpace = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"; // string.Empty;
        string nameSpace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing";

        //if (rootMsgElement.Name.LocalName == XName.Get("Envelope", rootNameSpace))
        //{
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("Action", nameSpace)).First().Value) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("MessageID", nameSpace)).First().Value) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("ReplyTo", nameSpace)).First().Value) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("To", nameSpace)).First().Value))
            {
                xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("Action", nameSpace)).Remove();
                xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("MessageID", nameSpace)).Remove();
                xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("ReplyTo", nameSpace)).Remove();
                xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("To", nameSpace)).Remove();
            }
        //}
        string updatedMsgString = rootMsgElement.ToString();
        // xdoc.Save(updatedMsgString);

        Message recreatedNewMessage = null;
        msOriginal = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(updatedMsgString));
        msOriginal.Position = 0;
        XmlDictionaryReader newXdr = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(msOriginal, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
        recreatedNewMessage = Message.CreateMessage(newXdr, int.MaxValue, request.Version);
        recreatedNewMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(request.Properties);

        request = recreatedNewMessage;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string errorMsg = ex.Message;
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            errorMsg += ex.InnerException.Message;
        }
    }
    return request;
}
```

As you can see, I have tried the set the position of the stream back to 0 but still doesn't help. I have also tried to push the message sans MessageID, ReplyTo, To & Action nodes directly to the endpoint and it fetches a proper response. Let me know if i am missing anything here.

Comment: Why do you need to remove these in the first place?  They are part of the SOAP spec so removing them makes you non-compliant?

Comment: Agree, the backend service is rejecting the message with these headers. We are now looking to create a simple routing service to send messages to backend service & receive a response from it.

Comment: Perhaps your issue is after the code you debugged. Install Fiddler and set the proxy settings in the send port to use it as a proxy. You can see exactly what is being sent and what is being received in return